# How to pass Ruby's STDIN to an external program called by Open3.popen3?

Tags: ruby, ffmpeg, stream, pipe, stdin

I would like to call ffmpeg from a Ruby script, lets call "vpipe", and I want this Ruby script to act as a filter like command: take its input from a pipe. Its only purpose is to select the first audio stream and delete chapters data if exists:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require "open3"

output_file=ARGV[0]

cmd=%Q{ffmpeg -y -i - -map 0:v -map 0:a -c:v copy -c:a:0 copy -map_chapters -1 #{output_file}}

Open3.popen3(cmd,:stdin_data=>STDIN)
```

Then I would like to call my program as follows:

```
curl http://www.example.com/video.wmv | vpipe processed.wmv
```

Unfortunately doesn't work, because there is no such an option for popen3 as :stdin_data. I also tried Open3.capture3 which can take this argument, but then I got en error message from curl: "Failed writing body".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your program is in the downstream of a piped command, its STDIN will be fed with the output of the previous command.

When you use `Open3.popen3`, you get the full control of the forked process' `STDIN`, `STDOUT`, `STDERR`. You need to manually feed it with the data you want, and consume the output as you wish.

```
Open3.popen3(cmd) do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
  # consume outputs in STDOUT and STDERR, otherwise the ffmpeg process may be blocked if it produces a lot of outputs
  Thread.new do
    while stdout.read
    end
  end
  Thread.new do
    while stderr.read
    end
  end
  while data = STDIN.read(64)  # read output of the upstream command
    stdin.write(data)          # manually pipe it to the ffmpeg command
  end
  wait_thr.join
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing out on a key feature of `popen3`, that is it will yield the handles to you and you can do whatever you want with them:

```
Open3.popen3(cmd) do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
  # Use stdin, stdout, stderr as you wish.
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If the last thing that "vpipe" does is calling another command and you want to pass stdin, stdout and stderr without modifications, then using `Open3.popen3` is a waste. Use `exec` instead! It is dead easy.